# How to make a rounded triangle using clip path

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to create a triangle shaped container using clip-path which has rounded corners.
So far I have managed to get the triangle but not sure on what is the best approach to take to get the rounded corners.

So far I have

HTML

```
<div class="shadow">
  <div class="triangle"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.triangle {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: blue;
   clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 50%, 100% 100%);
}

.shadow {
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 6px 3px rgba(50, 50, 0, .4));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using a polygon as a clipping path I am using a path: a triangle with rounded corners:

```css
.triangle {
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(https://assets.codepen.io/222579/beagle400.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip);
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.shadow {
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 6px 3px rgba(50, 50, 0, .4));
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0" class="svg-clip" style="position:absolute">
    <defs>
         <clipPath id="clip">
           <path d="M100.000,21.000 Q100,0 81.217,9.391L18.783,40.609 Q0,50 18.783,59.391L81.217,90.609 Q100,100 100.000,79.000Z" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
 
<div class="shadow">
  <div class="triangle"/>
</div>
```

In order to get a triangle with rounded corners I'm using this pen that helps me transform a polygon into a path with rounded corners.

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> do you know if there was a way using it from a path that if the width was responsive the path would scale with it?

In the next example the `<div class="triangle"/>` has a width and a height of 50vw.

Please take a look at the changes for the clipping path: The d attribute of the path is using now coords between 0 and one. Also the `<clipPath>` element has a new attribute: `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`

> clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"
>   This value indicates that all coordinates inside the `<clipPath>` element are relative to the bounding box of the element the clipping path is applied to. It means that the origin of the coordinate system is the top left corner of the object bounding box and the width and height of the object bounding box are considered to have a length of 1 unit value.

```css
.triangle {
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(https://assets.codepen.io/222579/beagle400.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width:50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip);
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.shadow {
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 6px 3px rgba(50, 50, 0, .4));
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0" class="svg-clip" style="position:absolute">
    <defs>
         <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
           <!--<path d="M100.000,21.000 Q100,0 81.217,9.391L18.783,40.609 Q0,50 18.783,59.391L81.217,90.609 Q100,100 100.000,79.000Z" />-->
           <path d="M1,.21 Q1,0 .81,.09L.187,.4 Q0,.5 .187,.59L.81,.90 Q1,1 1,.79Z" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
 
<div class="shadow">
  <div class="triangle"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, that looks good thanks, do you know if there was a way using it from a path that if the width was responsive the path would scale with it? i.e 200px x 200px

Comment: Thanks very much I understand this a lot better now