# Background-image in rounded triangle via svg clip path

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I need to create an image in a rounded triangle with blurred box shadow.

I try to do this with a clip path from an svg. I found some help in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453115/how-to-make-a-rounded-triangle-using-clip-path) old thread but i can't manage to change the radius of the corners. Is there any easy way to solve this? I tried to replicate it with Inkscape but without any succes so far.

Example I need to make: [Link to example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiMWr.png)

What i have so far:

```css
.image-shape {display:block;width:300px;height:300px;background-position:center;clip-path:url(#clip);-webkit-clip-path:url(#clip);}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0" class="svg-clip" style="position:absolute">
  <defs>
     <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
       <path d="M1,.21 Q1,0 .81,.09L.187,.4 Q0,.5 .187,.59L.81,.90 Q1,1 1,.79Z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="image-shape" style="background-image:url(https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/1c1/links-1242361.jpg)"></div>
```

Comment: Try this https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/bJZRPb Use the slider to change the roundness

Comment: @enxaneta thanks I was looking for something like this for hours! I got it working now. Changed the coordinates between 0 and 1. Leave a comment so I can upvote your answer. :)